# How to prevent .NET base class usage?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm working on a project where I need to extend `WebClient` for a custom implementation, `MyWebClient`.

I also need to make sure that `MyWebClient` is the only version that's implemented by any developer on the project and no one uses the base `WebClient` class.

Is it possible to prevent the usage of `WebClient`, considering it's not code that I have access to?

Comment: This seems smelly. Why do you need to prevent usage of `WebClient`?

Comment: Why make a base class and child class if there is only ever one class to extend the base?  Move the code from the base class to the child class and be done with it.

Comment: @Servy I assume he means WebClient, in System.Net, is his base class. He's extending that and wants to ensure that users only ever instantiate his extended version.

Comment: What about telling all the developers. _"Use the new `MyWebClient` class only"_?

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? Because it's poor design?

Comment: My specific need is to ensure the User-Agent header is set to a specific value throughout the product. My hope was there would be a way to enforce it without simply saying "hey everyone, remember to use this subclass".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the features of `WebClient` you need, you could consider implementing `MyWebClient` as  proxy that exposes only the methods you allow to be used from a `WebClient` member.

**Example:**

```
public class MyWebClient
{
    private WebClient HiddenWebClient {get; set;}

    // proxy sample
    public void DownloadFile(string address, string fileName)
    {
        HiddenWebClient.DownloadFile(address, fileName);
    }

   // other proxy methods & your specific implementation come here.

}
```

After, you will need a dedicated ctor and a maybe a factory to instantiate `MyWebClient` properly.

This won't prevent your developers from using `WebClient` which would be far too difficult (see @gdoron suggestion, for instance), but will help avoiding its usage by mistake.

**Edit:**

From your last comment, I think that all you need is a Factory that will set the User Agent for all your `WebClient` instances.

Then, depending on your organization, you will need a strong communication about its usage (and maybe a search tool to look for `new WebClient()` in your projects).

```
public static class WebClientFactory
{
    public static WebClient Create()
    {
        WebClient result = new WebClient();
        result.Headers.Add("My Fancy User Agent");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping that some clever (and easy) mechanism for strictly enforcing this existed that I didn't know about. I guess I'm not surprised it doesn't. Ultimately, it seems like it really does come down to team communication. I like the extra options on keeping it more obvious for everyone on the team though!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to code review all the code and make sure that WebClient isn't being used. Another option is to schedule a nightly task and pull from the source control and search through each file in the project to see if they use WebClient instead of MyWebClient (might be easier to do using Roslyn). Bottom line is that this isn't a code issue (or shouldn't be) it should be a training issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need it, (which I seriously doubt it)The only way you can do it is with reflection.

When the application starts scan for the code of all the methods and classes in the `Assembly`, and check that they don't use the forbidden `WebClient` class.

I guess you won't do it...

Comment: Ugh, if that's the only option, you're right. I'd prefer just to hope that all the developers remember to implement their code correctly than to do it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ReSharper, you could use the "Search with pattern" feature, and set it up to offer to automatically convert the `WebClient` code to your `MyWebClient` just by pressing the magical ALT+Enter shortcut!

See: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Search_with_Pattern.html